# In C, char array and string array in c shows different size, but when compared they are same

Tags: c, arrays, strlen

In C while trying char arrays, I came up with this problem.

```
void main(){

    char buffer[5] = {'s','d','f','d','f'};
    char a[5] = "sdfdf";
    printf("%d\n", *a==*buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(buffer));
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(a));
}
```

Output is

```
1

sdfdf

sdfdf

5

6
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Agreed, it's pure luck that `strlen(buffer)` did not tell you `42`.

Comment: @WeatherVane or `12`.

Comment: If some tutorial, book, or instructor advised you to use `void main()`, find get a better one. Use `int main(void)`. (And you omitted `#include <stdio.h>`.)

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is the missing `'\0'`, to define a 5 characters string correctly and initialize it from an array of `char` with an initializer list this is how it should be

```
char buffer[6] = {'s', 'd', 'f', 'd', 'f', '\0'};
```

the second variant in your code si wrong because the array can only store `5` characters, so again

```
char a[6] = "sdfdf";
/*     ^ 6 instead of 5 */
```

you cannot expect any of the functions following that part of the code to work, when you have a missing `'\0'`.

All of the `printf()` with the `"%s"` spcifier and `strlen()` expect this last special value `'\0'` or `0` if you prefer, to be there, when it's not, then these functions invoke undefined behavior because they go beyond the end of the array searching for the `'\0'`.